# Adding new fields to ESRI AGOL Hosted FeatureService using REST

Tags: rest, esri

I am new developer to ESRI AGOL, I am able to 
1) Upload ShapeFile
2) Publish ShapeFile as a HostedService

Now I need to add few extra fields to the featureService layer.
I tried to post fields collection to /addToDefinition end point, response is Sucess, but when I check the featureService layer, I do not see the newly added fields

Any suggestions  please